# put a comma between two characters

Tags: php

I have this string: `"09001200"` and I need to turn it on this another string: `"09:00 - 12:00"`.

Is there any function in php that put a specific character between two characters? like a ":" between that 90.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by `sustr_replace` method

```
$newString = substr_replace($oldString, $char_to_insert, $pos, 0);
```

Example:

```
echo substr_replace("09001200", ":", 2, 0);
```

Output: `09:001200`

Complete code:

```
$old = "09001200";
$new = substr_replace($old, ":", 2, 0);
$new = substr_replace($new, " - ", 5, 0);
$new = substr_replace($new, ":", 10, 0);
echo $new;
```

Output: `09:00 - 12:00`

Answer (score 2):

The function  you're looking for  doesn't exist directly  (insert string
into string), but  you can simulate this  with the [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)
function.  The logic  is to  replace a  zero length  portion in  a given
position of a string:

```
$new_str = substr_replace({original}, {string to insert}, {position}, 0);
```

This obviously  will operates on one  character at a time.  And for this
reason, a regex based operation could be more practical. Here is another
approach with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$new = preg_replace('/(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)/', "$1:$2 - $3:$4", $input);
```

Comment: ty so much, I didn't knew preg_replace and is very practical.